# SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool [..] Max retries exceeded with url:

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have installed `docker` and `docker-compose` manually (not through snap) like this:

```
sudo apt install docker-compose
docker-machine create default
```

This is my env default setting:

```
$ docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1" export
DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376" export
DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/home/adam/.docker/machine/machines/default" export
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

I then run

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Now I wanted to use this docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/moodle/

But calling

```
docker-compose up -d
```

returns this error:

```
ERROR: SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.99.100',
port=2376): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.22/info 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 
u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 
alert protocol version (_ssl.c:727)'),))
```

How may I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I added myself to the `docker` group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Comment: `usrmod` -> `usermod`

Comment: You're welcome! :) `myusername` may also be changed to `$USER`.

Answer (score 0):

When running docker-compose commands against the VCH docker-compose API you need to specify the version of TLS that you are going to use, in this case TLS 1.2 that is the one supported by VIC.

The way of specifying the TLS version for the docker-compose client is by setting an environment variable. The variable you have to use is COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION and it has to be equal to TLSv1_2.

```
export COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION=TLSv1_2
```